# ADF adding equals condition to existing if condition

Tags: azure, conditional-statements, azure-data-factory, etl

I have an if condition in an ADF activity like below:

```
@if(    
    contains(activity('LookupWmkLastUpdateConfig').output,'firstRow')
    ,greater(
        activity('LookupLastUpdateSrc').output.lastModified
        ,activity('LookupWmkLastUpdateConfig').output.firstRow.NewValueWatermark)
    ),
    false)
```

The if condition looks as the last update date in src vs my database. Want I want to include is an additional block of code that evaluates an outside parameter called TypeLoad.
The current set-up only allows for full loads, I want to be able to include delta loads.

Does anyone know how to include such a piece of logic to the existing if code?

```
equals(pipeline().parameters.FwkItem['TypeLoad'],1)
```

The above condition would for example evaluate the full or delta load.

All help is very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @and(equals(pipeline().parameters.FwkItem['TypeLoad],1),if(contains(activity('LookupWmkLastUpdateConfig').output,'firstRow'),greater(activity('LookupLastUpdateSrc').output.lastModified,activity('LookupWmkLastUpdateConfig').output.firstRow.NewValueWatermark)),false) -> this gives throws an error the function if does not accept 2 arguments.

Comment: you need to move the 'if' to the outside so the 'and' is the condition in the if, maybe this: @if(and(equals(pipeline().parameters.FwkItem['TypeLoad],1),contains(activity('LookupWmkLastUpdateConfig').output,'firstRow'),greater(activity('LookupLastUpdateSrc').output.lastModified,activity('LookupWmkLastUpdateConfig').output.firstRow.NewValueWatermark)),false)

Comment: This then returns:  function 'and' does not accept 3 argument(s)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro this in my environment. I gave the same expression

```
@if(    
    contains(activity('LookupWmkLastUpdateConfig').output,'firstRow')
    ,greater(
        activity('LookupLastUpdateSrc').output.lastModified
        ,activity('LookupWmkLastUpdateConfig').output.firstRow.NewValueWatermark)
    ),
    false)
```

[image]

- Same error **function 'if' does not accept 2 arguments** is occurred.
- When the expression is looked into the reason for error, there were two closing parentheses near  `,activity('LookupWmkLastUpdateConfig').output.firstRow.NewValueWatermark)    )` .
- Same is highlighted in the above image.
- one parenthesis is removed and gave the expression as in below image.

```
@and(equals(pipeline().parameters.fwkitem,1),if(contains(activity('LookupWmkLastUpdateConfig').output,'firstRow'),greater(

activity('LookupLastUpdateSrc').output.lastModified

,activity('LookupWmkLastUpdateConfig').output.firstRow.NewValueWatermark)

,false))
```

[image]

Expression doesn't produce any error now.